# Как показать блок, если у определенного display:block;?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как показать блок `.i-am-hiding` только тогда, если у `.i-am-visible` активно значение `display:block;` ?
Благодарю!

```js
let one = document.querySelector('.i-am-visible');
let two = document.querySelector('.i-am-hiding');

if (one.style.display == 'block') {
two.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="i-am-visible">
1111
</div>
<div class="i-am-hiding"style="display:none;">2222</div>
```

Comment: @Drakonoved поправил вопрос

Comment: @Qwertiy♦ поправил вопрос

Comment: Непонятно, что значит активно. Каким образом оно меняется?

Comment: @Qwertiy https://codepen.io/MorrisJerrald/pen/jOOKGpy суть в том, что когда второй таб становится видимым (при нажатии на родителя-вкладку через display: bock;) должен появляться скрытый блок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае нужно получить все стили элемента после применения **всех css**.
Если бы вы указали стили инлайн в `html`, тогда можно через свойство `style` элемента `.i-am-visible` сделать проверку. Поэтому используем `window.getComputedStyle()`.

Подробнее про `window.getComputedStyle()` на **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)**.

```js
let one = document.querySelector('.i-am-visible');
let two = document.querySelector('.i-am-hiding');

let stylesOfone = window.getComputedStyle(one)

if (stylesOfone.display === 'block') {
  two.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div class="i-am-visible">1</div>
<div class="i-am-hiding" style="display:none;">2</div>
```